# Programmer's editor (or its plugin) which opens Alternate Data Streams (ADS)

Tags: windows, text-editor, alternate-data-stream

I'm searching for programmer's editor or its plugin which can **create, discover, open and save [NTFS alternate data streams (ADS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29) using the user interface.**

Currently I am using [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) which can work with ADS if they are open from command line:

```
notepad++ D:\data\mydata.csv:sql_query
```

So in this example I can keep SQL query which led to creation of content of the CSV file in the same CSV file. This is fine to maintain using the command line. But when I am in Notepad++ user interface, I cannot discover that `mydata.csv` has `sql_query` ADS attached nor I can use file name `D:\data\mydata.csv:sql_query` in file open dialog.

Maybe some plugin can add the discovery into Notepad++ or is there some different programmer's editor (preferably free) which can work with ADS (discovery, opening, editing, saving)?

Example – I expect to be presented with the following file list:

```
D:\data\mydata.csv
D:\data\mydata.csv:sql_query:$DATA
```

(This is what command line `dir /R` does.) From this list, I can pick either main or alternate data stream to open in the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com)** editor has new plugin "NTFS Streams". It allows all you wanted:

- List streams and open "filename:stream" in this editor
- Add new stream, empty or from any file
- Delete streams

Plugin adds items in the "Plugins" menu.